# VirtualHosts: can't have more than one at the same time

Tags: apache

Can't seem to figure this one out. I want to have 2 ViritualHosts in my local machine. Both with different server names. Here's what I have in my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/MyName/Documents/Work/dev/project"
    ServerName work.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/work.local.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/work.local.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/MyName/Documents/Work/dev/project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/MyName/Documents/Personal/Dev/project"
    ServerName dev.shop
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dev.shop.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dev.shop.com-access_log" common
    <Directory "/Users/MyName/Documents/Personal/Dev/project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   work.local
127.0.0.1   dev.shop
```

Only one works, whichever I put first, the second one always goes to the DocRoot of the first one. So the ServerName itself works, but it's using the wrong DocRoot.

Why oh why? What am I missing?

I'm on Mavericks, by the way.

Comment: `work.local` != `inspire.local`.

Comment: You are totally right, but that was my failed attempt to hide the real names on my setup. On the real files those do match. I corrected it to avoid confusion. Thanks for pointing that out, tho.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the hosts file should be:

```
127.0.0.1   inspire.local dev.shop
```

All aliases for an IP have to be on the same line. This has nothing to do with Apache, it's how `/etc/hosts` is parsed by the system in general.

Comment: I tried that but it made no difference. Still good tip, though, didn't know you can put them all in one line. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Turns out `NameVirtualHost` dictates how the VirtualHosts will be picked up. So in my case, both Virtualhosts were declared like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
```

That didn't match my `NameVirtualHost` so it used the first one by default.

I changed them to match exactly, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

And now they work.

Damn.

Hope this helps other folks.